# How do I replace values in column B with other values in column B associated with the same value in column A in R?

Tags: r

Not sure if this is possible, but I am trying to tell R that if there are two different possible values in column B for a unique value in column A, and one of those column B values is "Unknown", replace "Unknown" with the other column B value associated with the same column A value.

For example, in this simple dataset, I would like 'Unknown' in [2,2] to be replaced with "Red", because there is another instance of group "A" which is color "Red". However, "Unknown" in [4,2] would not be replaced because there is no other color value for group "C".

```
group <- c("A","A","B","C","B")
color <- c("Red", "Unknown", "Red","Unknown","Pink")
df <- data.frame(group, color)
```

Comment: It is pretty simple to do, e.g. making 'lookup table' with distinct values of group colours and then replacing Unknown with the corresponding entry. However, it it not clear in this instance how to deal with B that is associated with both Red and Pink.

Comment: Thank you, I will research using lookup tables to solve this in R! I figured there would be a simple solution but I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

group <- c("A","A","B","C","B")
color <- c("Red", "Unknown", "Red","Unknown","Pink")
df <- data.frame(group, color)

> df
  group   color
1     A     Red
2     A Unknown
3     B     Red
4     C Unknown
5     B    Pink

df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(color2 = ifelse(color == "Unknown",
                                                   ifelse(length(color[which(color != "Unknown")])==0,
                                                           "Unknown",
                                                           color[which(color != "Unknown")]),
                                                   color))


# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
  group color   color2 
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1 A     Red     Red    
2 A     Unknown Red    
3 B     Red     Red    
4 C     Unknown Unknown
5 B     Pink    Pink
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

First `group_by` the `group` column, since you want to have some operations based on the `group`. Then use an `if_else` statement to find values that match "Unknown" **AND** also have more than one row in `group`. Replace these values with a random choice of colour present within `group`, and if the condition is not met, replace them with their original values.

Therefore, in a hypothetical case, when you have a "Unknown" value in B, it'll replace that "Unknown" with a random choice of "Red" or "Pink".

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(color = ifelse(color == "Unknown" & n() > 1,
                         sample(
                           grep("Unknown", 
                                str_split(paste0(color, collapse = ","), ",", simplify = T), 
                                value = T, 
                                invert = T), 1
                         ), 
                         color))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   group [3]
  group color  
  <chr> <chr>  
1 A     Red    
2 A     Red    
3 B     Red    
4 C     Unknown
5 B     Pink
```

### Your dataset

```
  group   color
1     A     Red
2     A Unknown
3     B     Red
4     C Unknown
5     B    Pink
```

Comment: This works on the example given, but not in a more general case. Add another row of group="A", and color="Red" to see.

Comment: Thanks for point out my mistake! I wasn't thinking thoroughly. Updated my answer to include `sample` for random selection :)

Comment: Sorry to point it out again, but the problem also lies in your `n()>1`.  For example, if the unknown for a group was the first row, this would still fail..

Comment: You're brilliant! Thanks again for letting me know! There's so much more to learn about the coding mindset!!! I think my previous problem isn't with `n() > 1`, but with my previous `gsub()` tactics. I believe my edited answer works fine now :)

Comment: Thank you so much! The explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solution:

```
left_join(df,
          df %>% filter(color!="Unknown") %>% 
            distinct() %>% 
            group_by(group) %>% filter(n()==1) %>% 
            rename(new_color=color)) %>%
  mutate(color=if_else(color=="Unknown", new_color, color)) %>% 
  select(!new_color)

  group color
1     A   Red
2     A   Red
3     B   Red
4     C  <NA>
5     B  Pink
```

Here is a data.table solution

```
library(data.table)
df = merge(setDT(df),unique(df[color!="Unknown"])[, if(.N==1) .(nc=color), by=group],all.x=T) %>% 
  .[, `:=`(color=fifelse(color=="Unknown",nc,color),nc=NULL)]

   group color
1:     A   Red
2:     A   Red
3:     B   Red
4:     B  Pink
5:     C  <NA>
```